# Define Bayesian Network and do Parameter Training with pgmpy

Tags: bayesian-networks, pgmpy

I want to create a BayesianNetwork with pgmpy in python. I know the names of my nodes, and the edges, essentially the structure of the graph of my Bayesian network. I want to train the Bayesian network with 'labeled' data; this means I do not have CPDs or TabularCPDs defined beforehand. So I know the nodes, the edges, and the states (e.g. low/medium/high) that my node variables can take. How do I build a Bayesian network model/object using pgmpy? I saw multiple examples (linked below) but I do not understand the part on how I can define what states my observable and fault variables can take.

In this [Parameter Learning example](https://pgmpy.org/detailed_notebooks/10.%20Learning%20Bayesian%20Networks%20from%20Data.html), data is available and the 'BayesianModel' is defined. I have data and I can put it in a similar pandas dataframe format. I am using 'BayesianNetwork' instead of 'BayesianModel'. I do not understand what is happening from section 10.1.1. State counts onward. For defining my BayesianNetwork, I have a dictionary of observed_variables and fault_variables, and another list of tuples defining the edges. How do I define it in the same way as in the example?

In another example here, [Parameter Learning in Discrete Bayesian Networks](https://pgmpy.org/examples/Learning%20Parameters%20in%20Discrete%20Bayesian%20Networks.html), the model used is from an example so the BayesianNetwork object is already defined with all the correct attributes, but I want to build my own, so it is unclear how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter learning example, the state counts is just an analysis step to understand the data. I will show a straightforward example here.

Simulate some data that we will use to learn the network parameters/CPDs.

```py
from pgmpy.utils import get_example_model
model = get_example_model('alarm')
df = model.simulate(int(1e4))
edges = list(model.edges())
```

Let's say for our model we want to use the edge list: `edges` and the dataset: `df`.

```py
# Create a model with edges
from pgmpy.models import BayesianNetwork
model = BayesianNetwork(edges)

# Learn the model CPDs using the given dataset
model.fit(df)

# Print one of the learned CPD
print(model.cpds[0])
```

The `fit` method by default does a Maximum Likelihood estimate of the CPDs. You can also pass the `estimator` argument to use `BayesianEstimator`.

Comment: I used the following to define the states that my variables can take:

model.fit(data=data, estimator=MaximumLikelihoodEstimator, state_names=variable_states)

I got a warning ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgmpy/factors/discrete/CPD.py:332: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in divide
  tabular_cpd.values = (cpd / cpd.sum(axis=0)).reshape(tabular_cpd.cardinality)". I am trying to solve this, but I have another error when I use VariableElimination: "ValueError: Sum or integral of conditional probabilities for node <variable_name> is not equal to 1."

Comment: @hunterlineage Could you maybe create an issue on the GitHub repo with some reproducible code so that I can figure out what exactly is happening?